Can Chandipath be done to increase a students intelligence in studies?
As student I want to be more intelligent , have more intellect and focus, better emotional strength . Can Chandipath help me gain that ? Which chapter should I recite to gain such benefits ? Also are there any other hymns to do that ?

Reciting a particular mantra from Devi Mahatyam (or Chandi) is sufficient for that purpose ..reciting the whole Chandi is not necessary for that and more over reciting Chandi is a difficult process and it requires proper knowledge and guidance .. just recite this mantra 108 times --- ya devi sarva bhuteshu budhirupena samstitha .... namastasyai namo namaha for increasing medha or buddhi.

Thank you @Rickross.
